# Google calender event link not using colorId parameter

Tags: google-calendar-api

I want to dynamically generate links for adding events to a google calendar.

The example I am using looks like this:

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=Test&location=Northpole&dates=20240226T190000Z%2F20240226T220000Z&colorId=11
```

It uses every other parameter correctly but `colorId` does not have an effect.

Is it simply not supported vio link?

Comment: I would like to clarify what you'd like to change with the `colorId`. Are you perhaps trying to change the `event color` of the calendar to be created or the color of your primary or secondary calendar itself?